# How to move from update to a function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to Unity and I made an animation by fallowing a tutorial but it was to use the space bar but I want to use a button because it is a mobile game. In my code, you can see the update function that it says !IsMenuMoving && !IsDifficultyMoving but when I use that on the button function it says error and that the type or namespace is not found.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MenuAnimator: MonoBehaviour
{
private Animator animator;
private bool IsMenuMoving = false;
private bool IsDifficultyMoving = false;

void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}



void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && !IsMenuMoving && !IsDifficultyMoving)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsDifficultyMoving", true);
        animator.SetBool("IsMenuMoving", true);
        IsMenuMoving = true;
        IsDifficultyMoving = true;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsMenuMoving && IsDifficultyMoving)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsDifficultyMoving", false);
        animator.SetBool("IsMenuMoving", false);
        IsMenuMoving = false;
        IsDifficultyMoving = false;
    }
}

public void MoveMenu(!IsMenuMoving && !IsDifficultyMoving)
{
    animator.SetBool("IsDifficultyMoving", true);
    animator.SetBool("IsMenuMoving", true);
    IsMenuMoving = true;
    IsDifficultyMoving = true;
}

public void MoveMenuBack()
{
    animator.SetBool("IsDifficultyMoving", false);
    animator.SetBool("IsMenuMoving", false);
    IsMenuMoving = false;
    IsDifficultyMoving = false;
}
}
```

Thanks so Much

Answer (score 1):

You put an if state condition into the function's 'references'. The parentheses after a functions name is used to get information, it is not a condition statement. I would recommend putting ,

```
if(!IsMenuMoving && !IsDifficultyMoving){
    MoveMenu();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!